# TCL foreach is adding quotes to my index

Tags: arrays, foreach, tcl

I am creating an array and looping through the array, but for some reason the foreach command is adding quotes to the index.

I have the following code to initialize the array:

```
# Fill the region array for the 8 regions.
set regionBBox(SDQ1) "11262.000 1558.700 15489.000 1663.000"
set regionBBox(SDQ2) "6910.000 1558.700 11137.000 1663.000"
set regionBBox(SDQ3) "1550.000 7929.260 1665.000 12159.000"
set regionBBox(SDQ4) "1550.000 12283.820 1665.000 16511.000"
set regionBBox(SDQ5) "6654.000 21241.580 11393.000 21352.000"
set regionBBox(SDQ6) "11518.000 21241.580 16257.000 21352.000"
set regionBBox(SDQ7) "21246.000 11773.100 21354.005 15999.000"
set regionBBox(SDQ8) "21246.000 7418.540 21354.000 11647.000"
```

No quotes appear when I get the whole list:

```
lsort [array names regionBBox]
```

Results in:

```
SDQ1 SDQ2 SDQ3 SDQ4 SDQ5 SDQ6 SDQ7 SDQ8
```

But when I loop through the array the value of each $id includes double quotes.

```
foreach $id [lsort [array names regionBBox]] {
  echo "Index = $id"
  set bbox $regionBBox($id)
}
```

Results in:

```
Index = "SDQ6"
Error: can't read "regionBBox("SDQ6")": no such element in array
```

So why is foreach adding quotes?  How do I avoid adding quotes?

Comment: Doh!  Stupid rookie mistake.  I have $id where I should have just id.

Comment: Note that `echo` is a shell command. It will work as you expect in an interactive tclsh session, but not in a tcl script.

Answer (score 2):

It was a dumb rookie mistake: I had "$id" in the foreach where I should have had just "id".  Here is the fixed code:

```
foreach id [lsort [array names regionBBox]] {
  echo "Index = $id"
  set bbox $regionBBox($id)
}
```

Which results in:

```
Index = SDQ1
Index = SDQ2
Index = SDQ3
Index = SDQ4
Index = SDQ5
Index = SDQ6
Index = SDQ7
Index = SDQ8
```